# No Bootable device error after trying to dual boot ubunto 18.04 LTS with windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, bootloader, boot-repair

I installed ubuntu on drive D and my windows was on drive C...now after creating swap area, efi and ext4 in D my installation began...and was completed successfully but when the laptop restarted it said no bootable device found...
I can start ubuntu by going into...
 boot device options->boot from efi-> No volume label-> EFI -> Boot -> boot×64
Now my ubuntu will start and once it will start i have all my windows files in the partion C and computer works fine but i don't get the menu to start windows when i turn on the laptop...
And i have to repeat the steps as it always show no boot device found error after restarting....

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Consider [editing](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1210987/edit) your question to make it easier to read, by making the text more separated, using [markdown](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help), and by including screenshots of less textual errors.